# Javascript: scope of the function within a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

I have this strange problem and not able to understand how does the scope of the function works within a file.

### E.g.

```
function f3() {
}

function f2() {
   f3(); // Cannot find variable: f3
}

function f1() {
    f3(); // works fine
    f2(); // works fine
   }

f1();
```

## Edited

Actual Code.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

function fPrintObj(obj) {
    // Object properties
    var output = '';
    for (var property in obj) {
        output += property + ': ' + obj[property]+'; ';
    }
    console.log(output);
}

function  fGetXpathAd() {
    xPathAd = "//div[@class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 home-solutions-head']";
    console.log(xPathAd);

    var adcopy = document.evaluate( xPathAd, document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null);
    fPrintObj(adcopy);  //DOES NOT WORK
    return adcopy;  
}

function main(status) {

        console.log('Evaluating ad-copy.... ');
        var a = page.evaluate(fGetXpathAd);
        // fPrintObj(a);  // WORKS

    phantom.exit();
}

//  fSetRandomUserAgent();
page.open('https://www.position2.com', main );
```

---

Error

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: fPrintObj

phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():6 in fGetXpathAd
phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():8
phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():8
```

Comment: I cannot see how you are getting the "cannot find variable: f3" error you say you are getting. I suspect the above isn't the actual code causing the mentioned error.

Comment: your above code is working here, http://jsfiddle.net/X887z/1/ .. i guess there is some other problem. it would be better if you post your actual code

Comment: There is no issue with the code exactly as you've included it.  So, if you're having an issue, then your real code is not as simple as you've portrayed in your question.  You will have to disclose more of the real issue for us to be able to help.

Comment: May be f3 is in browser context and f1,f2 are in phantomjs context. Just a guess. Please post some code snippet.

Comment: I agree this sounds strange. I am running the complete code on PhantomJs.

Comment: Difficult to post the actual code as too many related dependencies.

Comment: You know there is a difference between declaring function f3... and var f3 = function... For the latter order matters. If you did var f2 =  function() { f3(); }; f2(); var f3 = function() {}; That would cause your error because you tried to use f3 before it was declared. The fact that you are getting a cannot find variable is evidence you are doing something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In phantomjs, page.evaluate is a page context and you can not call a function defined outside of it. You should pass your function as second argument to the page.evaluate like this:

```
function  fGetXpathAd(fPrintObj) {
    xPathAd = "//div[@class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 home-solutions-head']";
    console.log(xPathAd);

    var adcopy = document.evaluate( xPathAd, document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null);
    fPrintObj(adcopy);  //WILL WORK
    return adcopy;  
}

function main(status) {

        console.log('Evaluating ad-copy.... ');
        var a = page.evaluate(fGetXpathAd, fPrintObj);
        // fPrintObj(a);  // WORKS

    phantom.exit();
}
```

I hope this will help.